Ansible win_ping encounters SSLError(1, '[SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] when connecting to windows server
I am encountering an error in running ansible via jenkins pipeline and putty on a linux server connecting to a windows server.
The error indicated is
UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "ntlm: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='IP Address Here', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:1000)')))",
    "unreachable": true
}


I tried to replicate the S Channels and Cipher suites configuration using IIS Crypto from the original windows server to another test windows server but I cannot replicate the error above.
When I try to use ping command in my local, the destination servers can be found.
How could this error be eliminated in ansible? Thank you!
